# using base class pointer as argument to method

Tags: c++, abstract-class

The following test code demonstrates an issue that I am having in a much larger application.  In the application I have a service that "provides" several servers that are all derived from one base class.  I then use createInstance to get "access" to a specific server based on a server type ('n' used below).  dynamic_cast is then used to cast as the appropriate server.  This all works fine.

The problem is when I try to use the deleteInstance to go back to the service and delete it, cleaning up any internal server related data.  I cannot seem to find a good passing mechanism or if it is even valid way of achieving what I am doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MM
{
public:
    virtual ~MM() {}

    virtual void start() = 0;
};

class M1 : public MM
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        std::cout << "M1 start" << std::endl;
    }
};

class M2 : public MM
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        std::cout << "M2 start" << std::endl;
    }
    void start( const std::string strName )
    {
        std::cout << "M2 start - " << strName << std::endl;
    }
};

MM * createInstance( int n )
{
    if( 2 == n )
    {
        return new M2;
    }
    else
    {
        return new M1;
    }
}

void deleteInstance( MM * & pInstance )
{
    delete pInstance;
    pInstance = NULL;
}

void deleteInstance2( MM ** ppInstance )
{
    delete *ppInstance;
    *ppInstance = NULL;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    M1 *pM1 = dynamic_cast<M1 *>( createInstance( 1 ) );
    M2 *pM2 = dynamic_cast<M2 *>( createInstance( 2 ) );

    pM1->start();

    pM2->start();
    pM2->start( "test" );

    deleteInstance( pM1 );
    deleteInstance( pM2 );
    //deleteInstance2( &pM1 );
    //deleteInstance2( &pM2 );

    return 0;
}
```

To complete the info, the error that I am receiving for deleteInstance implementation:

```
68:25: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘MM*&’ from expression of type ‘M1*’
46:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void deleteInstance(MM*&)’
69:25: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘MM*&’ from expression of type ‘M2*’
46:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void deleteInstance(MM*&)’
```

and for deleteInstance2:

```
70:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘M1**’ to ‘MM**’
70:27: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void deleteInstance2(MM**)’
71:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘M2**’ to ‘MM**’
71:27: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void deleteInstance2(MM**)’
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that binding a pointer to the derived type with a reference to a pointer to the base type would break the type system. Consider this motivating example:

```
void resetPtr( base*& b ) {
   static base instance;
   b = &instance;
}
int main() {
   derived *d;
   resetPtr( d );        // Now d points to a base, not a derived object!!!!
}
```

While you can work around this as some other answer points out (for example through the use of templates that will infer the appropriate type and so on), I would recommend that you **redesign** and pass the pointer by value.

*Why is it a bad idea to reset the pointer to NULL after deletion?*

The problem with reseting the pointer to NULL is that it does not really solve any problem, and adds problems of its own.

It does not solve the problem of knowing whether pointers are valid in your application, as in the general case you can have more than one pointer to a given object, and because you only delete one of them, only one of the pointers will be reset to NULL, and you are left (at least in most cases) with the same situation you had in the beginning.

It can help hide bugs in the logic of your application: after you reset the pointer to NULL, any potential issue in your application by which you `delete` the pointer twice will be hidden, as it is safe to `delete` a NULL pointer. While you might think that this is a good idea --after all, it avoids crashing your application-- in the long term it is a bad idea, since the core issue is still there: the design fails to provide proper ownership semantics.

Comment: The current use case is to create the instance, use it to collect and control data, and then delete instance when done.  A one-to-one relationship for that process, not multiple pointers.  That is why it is createInstance and not getInstance, but I can see how it can be misused.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with base class vs. derived class pointers; the problem is simply that you've declared your method to accept a pointer to pointer to MM as an argument, and you're passing just a pointer to MM.

You could pass a pointer to MM by reference -- i.e.,

```
void deleteInstance( T* &pInstance ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I like what you're trying to do, but I can't put my finger on why - I think the idea is fine. .. but heres a way you could implement it .

```
template<typename T>
void deleteInstance( T * & pInstance )
{
  // This conversion is here so you get a nice error if 
  // you try to use it on a type that isn't derived from MM.
  MM* tmp = pInstance;
  delete tmp;
  pInstance = NULL;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a champ.  I like the internal conversion to keep the template associated with MM.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `deleteInstance` is not working is that you are taking a non-const reference to a temporary created by the conversion of M1* or M2* to MM*.

The reason why `deleteInstance2` is not working is that Derived** is not convertible to Base**. [This faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/proper-inheritance.html#faq-21.2) explains it very well.

Comment: I knew MM** did not feel right but was trying various combinations to see how to work it. thanks for the explanation